# How can we avoid redundancy code lines

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing few php code to execute some CRUD MySql query easily.After writing several lines i noticed, many codes are redundant like the following sample code:

```
function  get_data(){
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT col1, col2 FROM `table1` WHERE `col1` = :id";
    $params = array(':id'=> "xyz");
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($params);
}

function  set_data(){
    global $conn;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `table1` (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (:v1, :v2, :v3) ";
    $params = array(':v1'=> "x", ':v2'=> "y", ':v1'=> "z");
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($params);

}
```

and UPDATE() , DELETE() and so on functions.

If notice that, many codes are same (e.g: prepare(), execute()) except the sql command & data

I try with bellow approach to unify them:

```
function execute_crud($sql, $param){
    global $conn;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($params);
}
```

But i think it still need something else.

My question is is there any better way to write it with such redundancy.

Comment: The easy answer is "Yes", because there is always a better way. It just depends who you ask, and I think your solution is fine. I'm not a huge proponent of writing plain SQL within my PHP code, but judging from the complexity, you're still a beginner. You already use prepared statements, which is great! So long answer: yes, but this really is fine for the amount of complexity you showed.

Comment: One big thing is to stop using `global` and like all of the other data, pass your database connection round as a parameter.  Or if you use classes, pass it into the constructor and store it.

Answer (score -1):

Use some ORM or even better - use some FRAMEWORK - which allow you to avoid create many lines of code. For example very good php framework is [LARAVEL (link to ORM doc)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent)

Comment: in a ORM or a FRAMEWORK you still need to write a pretty big OOP model code or generate OOP model code from SQL tables some framework allow this..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Actually in laravel you DON't need to write big OOP model - in fact you model can be almost EMPTY class

Comment: Also might be true then your IDE autocomplete will then not work so you need to remember the properties/functions and write more code on your own.. I like it when i can do `$user = new User(); $user->` IDE autocompletes  now finds all public properties or functions..

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski except for you've loaded an entire framework consisting of hundreds of thousands lines of code so you can write 1 line less code. Unless you need lots of other functionality from said framework, I'm going with OP's solution every time.

Comment: Framworks like Laravel was created among others to avoid write redundant code lines (or to "to reinvent the wheel") and speed up app creation.